# Mysql select to get only part of a row from a column

Tags: mysql, select

I have a table with a column that contains a string of numbers and I only want to return the last couple of digits.

For example:

```
column1 | column2
_________________
Blah    | 1231357
```

I need a select that will return the last couple of digits from the second column.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `RIGHT` function:

```
SELECT RIGHT(column2, 3) AS LastDigits FROM TableName
```

Change `3` to the number of digits you want.

Answer (score 1):

A modulus operator will take only the last two digits.

```
SELECT MOD(column2, 100) FROM mytable
```

Change 100 to 1000 to get three digits, etc.